# placeholder for file input

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to place "cv" in place of "no file chosen" ,I tried to add placeholder on the file input but it doesn't work

[image]

```
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group ">

          <input type="file" class="col form-control text-field-box mt-3" name="cv" id="files" placeholder="CV" accept="application/pdf" required />
          <label class="ml-3 " 
          style="font-size: 13px;position: absolute;top: 0px;
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;font-weight: 300;">CV</label>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code carefully and let me know if you have any question regarding for the same. :)

Hope it will help you.

```css
.file-wrapper .col.form-control{
height: 20px;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

.file-wrapper .ml-3{
font-size: 13px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 form-group file-wrapper">

    <input type="file" class="col form-control text-field-box mt-3" name="cv" id="files" placeholder="CV" accept="application/pdf" required />
    <label class="ml-3 " 
    style="font-size: 13px;position: absolute;top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;font-weight: 300;">CV</label>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of achieving this is hiding the input itself and use the label as a 'fake input' by styling it the way you want it. You must have an **id** on the input and **for** attribute on the label (the same as the id) so when you click the label it will trigger the input. And then with some basic javascript you can change the content of the label e.g. placeholder when nothing selected and the file name when is selected.

Example of hiding the input:

```
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.1px;
    z-index: -1;
```